# understanding destructuring in renderItem property in <FlatList /> in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, destructuring

I came across the following React Native code online:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([
    { name: 'shaun', id: '1' },
    { name: 'yoshi', id: '2' },
    { name: 'mario', id: '3' },
    { name: 'luigi', id: '4' },
    { name: 'peach', id: '5' },
    { name: 'toad', id: '6' },
    { name: 'bowser', id: '7' },
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <FlatList 
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
        data={people} 
        renderItem={({item}) => ( 
          <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
        )}
      />

    </View>
  );
}
```

I do not quite following the snippet related to the `renderItem` property. why are we using the destructuring syntax `{item}` . Also this is an object destructuring syntax (using curly braces), but in object destructuring we use keys as variable names. So I am afraid I am completley at a loss to understand the snippet below.

```
<FlatList 
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
        data={people} 
        renderItem={({item}) => ( 
          <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
        )}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this...

```
renderItem={({item}) => ( 
  <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
)}
```

actually mean....

```
renderItem={(props) => ( 
  <Text style={styles.item}>{props.item.name}</Text>
)}
```

This technique is called object destruction
check out for more info - https://medium.com/podiihq/destructuring-objects-in-javascript-4de5a3b0e4cb

Comment: ah that works now. but i was under the assumption that props are passed between components and not within the same component.

Comment: yeah.. you can take renderItem as a component holder where......
({item}) => ( 
  <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
)... is a arbitrary functional component

Comment: so in React, "props" is basically an object, and that is why we can destructure the item key on that object.

Comment: yes... you are correct. You can use multiple by separating by ,